# Why is Microsoft Word is showing weird formatting?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, text-formatting

I am using Microsoft Office 365 on macOS Sierra and a few days ago I was using Word to make some documents.

After some work I saved my work closed Word and reopened my files then there’s was a strange change in how Word shows hyperlinks, page footers, and table of content.

Here is what i am referring to. Why is this happening?

[image: Screenshot of the weird formatting.]

Comment: Those are supposed to be [Fields](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/list-of-field-codes-in-word-1ad6d91a-55a7-4a8d-b535-cf7888659a51). Did you perhaps change some settings in Word? Did anyone work on these documents with something other than Word (LibreOffice, Pages, ...)?

Comment: @DanielB yes perhaps there was change in settings "show fields instead of values"
as mentioned in answer provided below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention the version of Word you are using (Windows or Mac, Desktop or Online, Office365 or a permanent version such as 2019, 2016, 2013, 2010, 2007) and assuming it is a Windows Desktop version ... open the Word Options dialog and under Advanced. Scroll to the "Show document content" group. Verify control marked in the following screen clip. If it is marked, clear it.

If your version is something other than what I have assumed, please edit your original question and add the information. If you have edited the document with some other software, let us know.

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir , this was the problem . this doesn't matter now but u have updated office version in question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that you can toggle field code display
using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> without having to change the options.

Answer (score 0):

You can also right-click on any field code, or select any portion of a document, and then use the context menu to toggle the display of field codes on or off.

Comment: This seems to be equivalent to Shift+F9.  It should be noted that this affects only the selected field(s). Is there any reason to do this rather than Alt+F9 (which affects **all** fields in the document)?